# Is there an homemomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Is there an example of an homeomorphism from the reals onto itself that fails to be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner aren't homeomorphisms required to be bijective? I think a function like $x \mapsto x/2$ for $x > 0$ and $x \mapsto x/3$ for $x \leq 0$ would work. It is continuous and so is its inverse. Since it is not differentiable at 0, it fails to be a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $f(x)=x^3$: its derivative vanishes at $0$, so its inverse is not differentiable at $0$.